# Good Ruby on Rails 3.2.1 galleries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am making webpage for primary school. Now I need to implement galleries. I am newbie at ruby on rails, so I want to ask you, guys, which is good gallery.

Thank you.

Comment: try to be a little bit more specific about what kind of gallery you are looking for. and image gallery. post a link to a site that does what you like, that would be a good start. i have a feeling that however you build the gallery, it will probably use jquery plugins to display in your html pages. as far as the html client end, i'd suggest reading an article like this: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/ to get some more ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with masterkrang, you need use jquery library, (I like http://fancybox.net/). From backend - use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I'm too late. Anyway I can suggest you my gem [hermitage](https://github.com/ImmaculatePine/hermitage) for frontend. And as gayavat said, [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) is great for backend.

So, you'll need

Gemfile:

```
gem 'hermitage'
```

Then

```
bundle install
rails g hermitage:install
```

Model with paperclip attachment:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file
  has_attached_file :file, styles: { thumbnail: '100x100>' }
end
```

And in your view:

```
render_gallery_for @images
```

That will generate gallery markup and add javascript image viewer.

Comment: This is an awesome gem!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no such a thing like 'a gallery implementation' in the Rails ecosystem. You've got to choose both a backend gem(library) and a front-end library(probably a jQuery plugin). Then, you wire them up as you wish.

As for the backend choice, you might want to check out this gem list:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads